# How to move a null to the end of array in java using FOR loop?

Tags: java, arrays

Assume there is only one null in an array. I am trying to move it right to the end using a for loop. this is what i tried.

```
    String example[] = new String[5];
    example[0] = "a";
    example[1] = null; 
    example[2] = "c"; 
    example[3] = "d"; 
    example[4] = "e";
```

I want the output to be : a,c,d,e,null. I want to able to move the null to the end regardless of its index using a FOR loop.

This is what i tried

```
    String asd[] = new String[creatureList.length];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < creatureList.length; i++) {
        if (creatureList[i] != null){

        asd[i] = creatureList[i];



        }
        creatureList = asd;
```

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Is your approach not working or are you looking for a better approach (better in terms of?) ?

Comment: my approach is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search for the `null` element and if found, shift all elements 1 position to the left. This code works even if there are more than 1 `null` elements in the array.

```
public class Test10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example[] = new String[5];
        example[0] = "a";
        example[1] = null; 
        example[2] = "c"; 
        example[3] = "d"; 
        example[4] = "e";

        for (int j=0; j<example.length; j++){
            if (example[j]==null){
                for (int k=j+1; k<example.length; k++){
                    example[k-1] = example[k];
                }
                example[example.length-1] = null;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j=0; j<example.length; j++){
            System.out.println(example[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the principle of bubble sort in here.
Try this

```
String example[] = new String[5];
example[0] = "a";
example[1] = null; 
example[2] = "c"; 
example[3] = "d"; 
example[4] = "e"; 

for(int i=0; i < example.length - 1; ++i) {
    if(example[i] == null) {
        example[i] = example[i+1];
        example[i+1] = null;
    }
}

for(String s : example)
    System.out.print(s + " ");
```

If you only need to print the values that way, try this

```
for(String s : example)
    if(s != null)
        System.out.print(s + " ");
System.out.print(null + " ");
```

Comment: This wouldn't be the most efficient way of doing it, but still should work.

Comment: I figured that out, but I almost never find a situation to use bubble sort (or at least its main idea). I just got carried out. =D

Comment: that's because it's known as one of the 'simple' sorts - if you're learning about advanced sorts, you might want to look at the 'advanced sorts'

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution without creating a new `Array` would be to move the elements.
Example, assuming that `example` is an `Array`:

```
boolean found = false;

for(int i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  if(found)
    example[i-1] = example[i];
  if(example[i] == null)
    found = true;
  if(i == example.length - 1 && found)
    example[i] = null;
}
```

I want to add that this would be a lot easier if you would use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) (for example an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), I highly recommend using them instead of `Array`s if performance is not a huge factor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a different implementation for `ArrayLists` (as `.remove()` is handy), but here we are with a bounded array:

```
for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
   if(null == array[n]) {
        // to avoid issues with references, unsure if necessary
        String s = array[n + 1];
        array[n] = array[s];
        array[n + 1] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is based on your assumption that there's only one `null`:

```
for (int i=1; i<example.length; i++) {
    if (example[i-1] == null) {
        example[i-1] = example[i];
        example[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers before me were not correct, so here is a code that works and puts all the nulls at the end of a array.

```
public static void moveNullToTheEnd( Object[] arr ) 
{
    
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length];
    int counter = 0;
    int nullcounter = arr.length-1;
    for(int i= 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == null){
            temp[nullcounter] = null;
            nullcounter--;
            
        }
        else {
            temp[counter] = arr[i];
            counter++;
            
        }
    }
    arr = temp;
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    
}   

    
public static void main (String[] args)
{
      Object [] test = new Object[] {1, 2, null, null, 4};
      moveNullToTheEnd(test);
}
```

Comment: Why you think the accepted answer is not correct? I have tested it and it seems to work as intended. This is a very old question and probably doesn't need anymore answers unless you have something new to add.