# Java: Move null values to the right of all non-null elements in 2D array using for loops only

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given `String[] [] arr2D = [["sun", "moon"], null, ["black", "white"], ["dog", "cat"], null]`, how can I loop through `arr2D` to shift the first `null` to the immediate right of `["dog", "cat"]` or to the end of the array so that `arr2D` becomes `[["sun", "moon"], ["black", "white"], ["dog", "cat"], null, null]`?

I have tried adapting [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787831/how-to-move-a-null-to-the-end-of-array-in-java-using-for-loop) involving 1D arrays but I ended up with a `nullPointerException` every time.

```
// I'm hardcoding i < 4 because there are 4 elements between and including ["sun", "moon"] and ["dog", "cat"]
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if(arr2D[i] == null) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
      arr2D[j - 1][0] = arr2D[j][0];
      arr2D[j- 1][1] = arr2D[j][1];
    }
    arr2D[4 - 1] = null;
    break;
  }
}
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot store to object array because "items[...]" is null`

Comment: If you edit your post to include what you've tried and the stack trace from the NPE we can more easily help you fix your your homework assignment. As it is you are asking people to jump through hoops in order to help you.

Comment: Apologies, check the post again

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution using only loops would be to create a new array and copy the non null values:

```
static String[][] moveNullsRight(String[][] arr){
    String[][] result = new String[arr.length][];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] != null){
            result[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you need to sort your array in place use something like below:

```
static String[][] moveNullsRight(String[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        int m = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
            if(arr[m] == null && arr[j] != null){
                m = j;
            }
        }
        String[] temp = arr[m];
        arr[m] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I should have been more specific; while `Comparator.nullsLast` looks very helpful, I was looking for a solution that only uses for loops. Perhaps I could view the source code of nullsLast

Comment: Apologies, check the post again.